# Libgdx 2D How to create dynamic fog for orthographic camera?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d

I am currently creating a top down type game in libgdx for android using an orthographic camera. I want to create dynamic fog, which means not just layer an image over the game. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: This link may be achieve you goal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549456/how-to-implement-a-ground-fog-glsl-shader

Answer (score 1):

[Particle effects](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor) seem to be useful here - all you need to do is to create fog particles in editor and then just add them to the screen

This way you can define where to display fog, how intensive it should be. It seems to be easier then creating your own shader and also will allow you to make some effects like *fog coming out from grate* (you just need to add Effector over grate's image) what is not very easy with shaders

To get information how to use Particle Effects you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/11/03/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-15-Particles-Part-One-2D-Particles.aspx) - there is example also