# glEnable(GL_FOG) does work; gives invalid enumerant error

Tags: opengl

When I include the line:

```
glEnable(GL_FOG);
```

In my OpenGL 3 file, I get the following error:

```
GL Error: invalid enumerant
Exception caught: GL Error: invalid enumerant
Program ended with exit code: 255
```

Is there a main motivating reason for this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a OpenGL 3 core profile? Because it's deprecated in 3 and removed in 3 core.

Comment: I am using OpenGL 3 core profile. Is there any way around it, or an alternative Fog capability in 3?

Comment: Write a shader that renders fog - replacing any deprecated fixed-pipeline feature would require writing your own shader.

Answer (score 1):

As the people pointed out in the comment under your question,your error stems from the fact you're using deprecated, [fixed pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) functionality while having OpenGL 3 core profile on.You are strongly suggested to use programmable pipeline and calculate fog effect in shaders.And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549456/how-to-implement-a-ground-fog-glsl-shader) you can learn how to do that.

As a sidenote,many newcomers to OpenGL still tend to use the deperecated API.Please don't do it,unless you abolutely must,for your own sake.Programmable OpenGL is a bit harder to start with,but it gives you much more freedom and possiblities of what you can do with your GPU.