# How can I set fog in scenekit to follow a curve?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am trying to get the fog in Scenekit to follow a curve from the starting distance to ending distance, rather than having it be linear. This is what the fog distance graph would look like:

[image]

What would be the best way to create a volumetrically stored fog opacity curve like this?

I know you can set the density curve to make it exponential/quadratic, and also tried that but I wanted to make this type of curve as well.

I tried changing `fogStartDistance` and `fogEndDistance` but the effect wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet from a Metal shader I have, this performs a "standard" fog look and feel. It was used in a MetalKit scene, so should work in SceneKit but you will have to figure out how to inject it into the scene. The fragment shader mentioned above would be a good place to start looking.

```
// Metal Shader Language
float4 fog(float4 position, float4 color){
    float distance = position.z / position.w;
    float density = 0.5;

// the line that does the exponential falloff of the fog as we get closer to camera
    float fog = 1.0 - clamp(exp(-density * distance), 0.0, 1.0);

// the color you want the fog to be
    float4 fogColor = float4(1.0);
    color = mix(color, fogColor, fog);
    return color;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I'll try i tout and update this page if I succeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [fragment shader modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypointfragment) to implement your own curve.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on this? Tha actual implementation of the fog, that is. I couldnt't find much for glsl fog.

Comment: the basic idea is to get the distance from the object to the camera. Then absorb light ("fog opacity") depending of that distance, according to a given curve. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549456/how-to-implement-a-ground-fog-glsl-shader

Comment: Could you explain the "light absorption" a little more? Would it be adding some sort of tint to the object material?

Answer (score 0):

That could definitely be done, but you will have to implement the fog yourself, as fog is just the ZDepth saved out and then multiplied over the final render pass.

You could model your curve as a nurbs/hermite curve or equation and then sample points along the curve.

Hermite has a time from 0 to 1(range from 0 to 1), this would correspond to the ZDepth value[0 at camera, 1 at farthest point].

The sampled point(could be any value depending how you modelled the curve) along the hermite(between range 0 and 1) would then be multiplied, against the ZDepth value.

FogStartDistance and FogEndDistance does a linear multiple over the distance, and sadly you can only specify the exponent of the blend.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I don't know how this would be done in Swift, or any language for that matter.

Comment: There two sections to your request. Getting a curve and sampling it, the second is metals ZDepth. I haven’t done this in SceneKit, but will try explains the bits and hopefully you can implement it :)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I understand sampling the curve, but still having a bit of a hard time with the actual fog part. Would i tint the node material or something?